# Live audio streaming from Java server to browser (Flash,HTML5)

Tags: java, audio, streaming

For a project, I need to be able to stream live audio from a Java server to the browser on the client. My first guess was to use RTMP with a Flash player, my second guess to make use of the HTML5 audio tag. But so far, I've failed to find anything useful (like a library), so does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Here's the setup: The sound comes in from a VoIP server as a bunch of PCM samples. From there, it has to go to get to the client, while usually only one client listens to one stream. So I need to be able to send many VoIP streams to several clients, a simple form of authentication would also be nice (like a token or a secret URL where the stream is located at).

So far, I've looked at Red5 (looks to me like one-to-many streaming only) and searched for Java-based RTMP libraries. Any help is gladly appreciated!

Comment: What I would advise doing is going around to different radio stations and talk show web sites and seeing what they are using to stream audio. I know of none off hand, but at least then you can kind of see what is available.

Comment: The thing is that radio stations all use a one-to-many streaming model. This could easily be done with Red5, but I need one-to-one.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this? I'm looking for the same.